# show positive and negative votes

Tags: theming, 6, rating

i'm trying to make a 'top voted' view of nodes and I want it to appear like this:

title of node; 655 positive, 120 negative votes, total 775.

how do i do the '655 positive, 120 negative votes' part?

Answer (score 0):

The [Vote Up/Down module](https://www.drupal.org/project/vote_up_down), while it supports Views 2 integration, only allows for a [Voting Up/Down widget](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/vote_up_down/tree/vud_node/views/vud_node.views.inc). With no support in the module for retrieving the vote count, you'll need to do one of the following:

1. Wait for the maintainer to add a views handler that supports up & down votes data.
2. Create your own patch that adds support for that data.

Given the current state of the project (seeking maintainer, 7.x version not released), you're probably going to have to go with #2.